# jQuery auto rename the selectors in clone div

Tags: jquery, clone, rename

1) Preamble.
I have a link that fire a jQuery method for cloning a div that contains a bunch of selector and all is within form.

2) The html code:

```html
<a href="" id="cloneMethod">Fire</a>

<form method="post" action="">
      <div class="colneDivs">
        <input type="text" name="1"/>
        <input type="text" name="2"/>
        <select name="3"></select>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="5" name="4"/>
        <input type="text" name="5"/>
        < ... and so on .../>
     </div>
</form>
```

3) The script:

```js
var iLast, nrCamp, cat, temp, cateCampuri;
$('#cloneMethod').on('click', function(){
    $('.cloneDivs:last').clone().insertAfter('.cloneDivs:last');
    iLast = $('.cloneDivs:last').find('input:last');      
    nrCamp = parseInt(iLast.attr('name'))+1;
    modiNume(nrCamp);
});

function modiNume(cat){
    temp = $('.cloneDivs:last');
    cateCampuri = temp.length;
    for(i=0; i < cateCampuri; ++i ) {
        temp.eq(i).attr('name',cat+i);
    }
}
```

4) The problem.

a) Any idea for:

```js
iLast = $('.cloneDivs:last').find('input:last');
```

to change:

```js
.find('input:last');
```

in something general like:

```js
.find('*:last');
```

I try:

```js
.find('*').last()
```

and it doesn't work.

b) I want to auto-change selectors name and this part:

```js
for(i=0; i < cateCampuri; ++i ) {
        temp.eq(i).attr('name',cat+i);
    }
```

from method modiNume doesn't work.
So any idea will be appreciated.

Edit: I made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JC4dv/1/

Comment: I will. I can't format code blocks in my question. I will ask some to edit my question, please.

Comment: @drLeo now better view..

Comment: thank you @sangram. probably I made something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no auto function to rename. I would suggest you to set an Id like txtname_0, txtDesc_0. and Use following code to clone

```
<a href="#" id="cloneMethod">Fire</a>
  <div class="colneDivs">
    <input type="text" id="txtName_0"/>
    <input type="text" id="txtId_0"/>
    <select id="txtSelect_0"></select>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="5" id="txtDesc_0"/>
    <input type="text" id="txtTest_0"/>
 </div>
```

and Jquery code:

```
$('#cloneMethod').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var clonedHtml = $('.colneDivs:last').clone(true, true).get(0);
 var newId = $('.colneDivs').length;
    console.log(newId);
 $(clonedHtml).find("*").each(function(index, element) {
     if (element.id || element.name) {
         var matches = element.id.match( /(.+)_\d+/ );
         if (matches && matches.length >= 2) {
             var splitedId = matches[1].split('_');
             var elementId = splitedId[splitedId.length - 1];
             element.id = elementId + "_" + newId;
         }
         if (element.name) {
             element.name = element.id;
         }
     }
 });
$(clonedHtml).insertAfter('.colneDivs:last');
});
```

Here if fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/kn4ZF/

Comment: I'm afraid that your code is wrong. It add same id's to all selectors in a div. I'm doing same think with for(i=0; i < cateCampuri; ++i ) {        temp.find('*').attr('name',cat+i);}. But this it'n not helping me at all. I want something  like this: selector1 name1 selector2 name2 selector3 name3 and after clone selector1 name4 selector2 name5 selector3 name6

Comment: I have provide you jsFiddle link and it is working fine there. just you have to give an Id to you input fields like txtName_0, txtDesc_0. and the function will take care rest of task.

Comment: Right, I got the trick, to name all different and append newId for each selector element of a new div. Thank you for trick.

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour and according @Rajesh Kumar tip, I simplify the problem and I got following full working code:

Html code:

```
<button id="cloneMethod">Fire</button>
<div class="colneDivs">
    <input type="text" name="a1" value="a1"/>
    <input type="text" name="b1" value="b1"/>
    <input type="text" name="c1" value="c1"/>
</div>
```

jQuery script code:

```
$('#cloneMethod').on('click', function () {
 $('.colneDivs:last').clone().insertAfter('.colneDivs:last');
 var nrCamp = $('.colneDivs').length;
 $('.colneDivs:last').children().each(function(){
     $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').substr(0,1)+nrCamp);
     $(this).val($(this).attr('name').substr(0,1)+nrCamp); // this must be removed. It is just for easing verify process...
 });
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JC4dv/16/